# Admob Banner on Top of layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob, banner

I want to display banner on top of the screen, but there is a problem. In my code (this is not my code, because I`m in learning process) I have two options. To show banner under or over the screen on bottom of screen.

```
    public void showBanner(final boolean inLayout) {
    //banner ad
    if (BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID.length() > 0) {
        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID);

        if (inLayout) {
            //make ad visible on bottom of screen over surface
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            adView.setLayoutParams(params1);
        } else {
            //make ad visible on bottom of screen under surface
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
            params.weight = 0;
            adView.setLayoutParams(params);

        }
```

If I change `params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);` from `BOTTOM` to `TOP`, banner is displayed over the screen on top. But if I change `params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;` from `BOTTOM` to `TOP`, ad is still showed on the bottom :(

Anyone can help me with this? Thanks so much!

inLayout code:

```
// Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                View parent = (View) adView.getParent();
                if (parent != null) {
                    if (!(parent.equals(layout) || parent.equals(linear_layout))) {
                        if (inLayout)
                            layout.addView(adView);
                        else
                            linear_layout.addView(adView);
                        recalculateScreen();
                    }
                } else {
                    //add new banner ad to screen
                    if (inLayout)
                        layout.addView(adView);
                    else
                        linear_layout.addView(adView);
                    recalculateScreen();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

//add relative layout to linear layout for banner ad mobility
    linear_layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linear_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linear_layout.addView(layout);

    setContentView(linear_layout);
    holder = surface.getHolder();
```

Comment: I know, but this code is already set and I`m newbie so...I must go with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all i think this code overall `View` is a `RelativeLayout` that has a `LinearLayout` that contains some other `View`s.. the first code aligns your addz to the bottom of the parent and the second code aligns it to the bottom of its container in the `LinearLayout` view container -(idk if i make sense)

but your initial edit works because its being aligned relatively to the parent, and your second edit, re-define's the position of the addview in its container.. so to change it  *in the else* code (assuming my logic is right)

```
   //make ad visible on bottom of screen under surface
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
   params.weight = 0;
   adView.setLayoutParams(params);
   // my addition starts here
   //inLayout is linearlayout, that was what i thought but no.
   ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) adView.getParent(); // your linear layout
   if(parent.getChildCount() >0){
         View viewToTake = parent.getChildAt(0); // taking the first child element
         parent.remove(parent.indexOfChild(adView)); // you get the index of the adview layout and remove it
         parent.addView(adView,0); // adding it at the first position
         parent.addView(viewToTake,parent.getChildCount());// adding the view we took out back into play, you can decide to add it as the
         // second element since it was your initial first with parent.addView(viewToTake,1);
```

**EDIT 1**
copy paste this and leave the first one..

```
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            View parent = (View) adView.getParent(); 
            if (parent != null) {
                if (!(parent.equals(layout) || parent.equals(linear_layout))) { 
                    if (inLayout)
                        layout.addView(adView); 
                    else
                        linear_layout.addView(adView,0); // adding it to linearLayout first element, that's what the zero does
                    recalculateScreen();
                }
            } else {
                //add new banner ad to screen
                if (inLayout)
                    layout.addView(adView);// same here
                else
                    linear_layout.addView(adView,0); //same here, goes to the top
                recalculateScreen();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}
for the relative layou you can do the align parent stuff

Comment: I added all code in main post related to linear_layout and inLayout...There I must put your code, if I understand right? :)

Comment: yes,in the else code of your initial code sample, but you can put it in the addition of views in the admob listener, let me try if i can edit that..@Karnak

Comment: Hmm, if I put in else part I got this error "Cannot invoke getChildCount() on the primitive type boolean"

Comment: that inlayout was supposed to be a view or ViewGroup so you can change that to `ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) adView.getParent();` then `if(parent.getChildCount() >0){` @Karnak

Comment: copy paste the second code and see @Karnak , btw who wrote the code?

Comment: you are my hero! Thanks for great lession how to write Java code! Your code work like a charm! :) Thank you so much... Btw, code is from one of the old android source code, but developer doesnt offer support anymore.